# CSS - div overlay responsive issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have  a couple of issues with an image overlay.

Basically I have 6 boxes that contain an image and a title overlay.  On the Click event, the title overlay is hidden and a text overlay is displayed which should cover the whole of the image.

Issues:

1. On click the overlay pushes down the other boxes, I cannot find where this is coming from.
2. The overlay is bigger the image when the box / image size is any other size but the default.  Therefore on smaller screen sizes the overlay overlaps the image.

   ```
   .vc_row-fluid {
    text-align:center;
   }

   .hr-banner {
       padding: 0;
       cursor: pointer;
       text-align:left;
       display:inline-block;
       max-width: 470px;
       max-height: 259px;    
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;    
   }

   .hr-banner > img {
       width: 100%;
   }

   .hr-banner-title {
       margin: 0;
       color: #FFF;
       line-height: 2em;
       margin-top: -3em;
       margin-left: 16px;
       font-size:24px;
       font-weight:bold;

   }
   .hr-banner-text {
       display: none;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       color: #FFF;
       font-size: 1.2em;
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
       max-width: 470px;
       max-height: 259px;    
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;  
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
   }

   .hr-banner-text p {margin:16px;}

   .hr-noselect {
       -webkit-touch-callout: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
   }



   <div class="hr-banner noselect">

   <img draggable="false" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nvq.jpg" alt="" />
   <h5 class="hr-banner-title">NVQs</h5>
   <div class="hr-banner-text">

   It is important that we allow our staff to take ownership of their own development. We currently have almost 100 employees studying for an NVQ across a variety of different specialisms – from business administration to management.

   </div>
   </div>
   ```

I realise this would probably work better if the image was a background image of the containing div, however, I did not write this code and and unable to change the structure, only the CSS.

many thanks

Comment: can you put together a demo on jsfiddle ?

Comment: could you please add a link to a demo of your code ?

Comment: yes doing one now...

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you mean:

```js
var hrBanner = document.getElementsByClassName('hr-banner')[0];

function showHideText() {
this.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0].classList.toggle('nodisplay');
this.getElementsByClassName('hr-banner-text')[0].classList.toggle('nodisplay');
}

hrBanner.addEventListener('click',showHideText,false);
```

```css
.vc_row-fluid {text-align:center;}

.hr-banner {
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width: 470px;
    max-height: 259px;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 259px;    
}

.hr-banner > img {
    width: 100%;
}

.hr-banner-title {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.hr-banner-text {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    max-width: 470px;
    max-height: 259px;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.hr-banner-text p {margin:16px;}

.hr-noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.nodisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr-banner noselect">

<img draggable="false" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nvq.jpg" alt="" />
<h5 class="hr-banner-title">NVQs</h5>
<div class="hr-banner-text nodisplay">

It is important that we allow our staff to take ownership of their own development. We currently have almost 100 employees studying for an NVQ across a variety of different specialisms – from business administration to management.

</div>
</div>
```